# "error retrieving current directory" running psql commands under sudo

Tags: bash, postgresql, sudo

from a bash script I´m trying to create a postgresql database + users.
It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ' Create DBs'
sudo -u postgres createdb -E 'utf-8' -l en_US.utf8 -T template0 testdb
echo ' Create User'
sudo -u postgres  psql -c "create role bert with login password 'pass';"
echo ' alter permissions'
sudo -u postgres  psql -c "alter database testdb owner to bert;"
```

unfortuantely I´m getting following errors:

```
==> default: Create DBs
==> default: could not identify current directory: No such file or directory
==> default: Create User
==> default: shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
==> default: CREATE ROLE
==> default: alter permissions
==> default: shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

I would be very thankful if one coule explain what´s going wrong and how to work around the getcwd error.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is being run from somewhere (such as `/root` -- or possibly a previously-deleted temporary directory) where the `postgres` user does not have access to the current working directory.

These messages are effectively harmless (unless you're invoking scripts that depend on `$PWD` or similar variables or commands), but if you want to avoid them, change directories to somewhere certain to exist and which the `postgres` user has access to. For instance, put the line:

```
cd /
```

...at the top of your script, just under the shebang.

Comment: I just had this problem when running psql inside a VM Vagrant/Homestead, in which I used a mapping for a directory on my local machine and then I had to delete/replace the entire directory. On the terminal I didn't bother to cd .. then cd folder again, so "a previously-deleted directory" case.